# Swift Array Sort by Property Error : Instance method 'localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare' requires that 'String?' conform to 'StringProtocol'

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, object

I am trying to sort this array of custom objects and I get the following error:

> Instance method 'localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare' requires that
> 'String?' conform to 'StringProtocol'

```
filteredCountriesAndCities?.sorted(by: {$0.countryName?.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1.countryName) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the situation when `countryName` is nil, here is an example sorting nil values last

```
let sorted = array.sorted {
    guard let first = $0.countryName else {
        return false
    }
    guard let second = $1.countryName else {
        return true
    }

    return first.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(second) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
}
```

Comment: @TheBear if you want the nil properties to be at the start of the collection you can simply do `$0.countryName?.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1.countryName ?? "") == .orderedAscending`

Comment: Thanks for that tip Leo

Comment: I owe you a bear! Cheers <3